# How to wrap an element in a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm trying to wrap elements except one in a popup. Everything I do doesn't work. For example.

In this div (figure or `.leaflet-popup-content` div) I want to wrap all text, title image, in fact everything except the figure or iframe in order to easily add some padding, without having to select all the element one by one.

```
 <div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 301px;">
   <figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is- 
    provider-youtube wp-embed-aspect-16-9 wp-has-aspect-ratio">
     <div class="wp- block-embed__wrapper">
       <iframe ...></iframe>
     </div>
   </figure>
   <h2>some title</h2>
    <p>som text.</p>
 </div>
```

I tried many ways, like :

```
 jQuery('.leaflet-popup-content').not('.wp-block-embed-youtube 
 ').wrapAll('<div class="inner"> 
  </div>');
```

But absolutly nothings happens.

Comment: So why are you not just adding a CSS rules to do it? `.leaflet-popup-content h2, .leaflet-popup-content p { padding-left: 200em' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the jQuery calls to get the children elements and filter out the figure.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#doWrap").click(function(){
        jQuery('.leaflet-popup-content').children().filter(":not(figure)").wrapAll('<div class="inner"> </div>');
    
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 301px;">
  <figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is- 
   provider-youtube wp-embed-aspect-16-9 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div 
   class="wp- block-embed__wrapper">
   <iframe></iframe>
    </div></figure>
    <h2>some title</h2>
    <p>som text.</p>
</div>

<button id="doWrap">Wrap</button>
```

Comment: thank you yes, but it doesn't work..nothing is wrapped..and in fact, there could also have img, text not in p tag, so my goal is to wrap everything except the ifram in one div..is it because the popup is not opened by default ?? is there something to to with a click event ??

Comment: I changed it as your commnents and also added the browser's inspect screen to show before and after clicking the "wrap" button. (Run the snippet and check the ispect to verify the results)